# GDAL Virtual File Systems Python Opening files in Network Drive Issue

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, ogr

I'm trying to open a .tar file using `/vsitar/`

The file to be opened is located at: `//my_network_drive/scratch/my_file.tar`

In Python I have the following snippet:

```
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
driver.Open(/vsitar//my_network_drive/scratch/my_file.tar/my_file.shp`
```

This does not seem to work even though the file exists.

However, if I were to map the network drive say to Z

```
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
driver.Open(/vsitar/Z:/scratch/my_file.tar/my_file.shp`)
```

This does work.

The documentation seems to show that what I want to achieve is possible
`/vsitar//home/even/my.tar/subdir/my.tif # (absolute path to the .tar)`
https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsis3

Does anyone know a way to fix this without having to specifically map a drive?

Answer (score 3):

The following path seems to work now:
`/vsitar///my_network_drive/scratch/my_file.tar/my_file.shp`

Comment: +1 `'/vsitar/' +  '//my_network_drive' is three slashes, not two.